# Is the following statement true about convergent series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am writing a proof  for a topology course, and in this proof I used the following "fact":

Let $\underset{j = 1}{\overset{\infty}{\Sigma}}x_j$ be a convergent series of nonnegative reals, and let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Then there is a positive integer $L$ so that
$$\underset{j = L}{\overset{\infty}{\Sigma}}x_j < \epsilon$$
My proof is heavily reliant on this statement being true, and while it feels correct I'm still beating myself up over it. Is this a known statement or do I need to go back to the drawing board?

Comment: It's clear: the partial sums converge to the sum of the series, so the tails must converge to zero. Just take $L$ big enough so that $\sum_{j=1}^{L-1}x_j$ is within $\epsilon$ of the sum of the series.

Comment: You can use Cauchy criterion.

Answer (score 1):

Its true. Note

$$ \sum_{j=1}^\infty x_j  = \sum_{j=1}^{L-1}x_j + \sum_{j=L}^\infty x_j$$

But also by definition $$\lim_{L\to \infty}  \sum_{j=1}^{L-1}x_j = \sum_{j=1}^\infty x_j,$$ so moving the $\sum_{j=1}^{L-1}x_j$ term to the left-hand side and sending $L\to\infty$, 
$$\sum_{j=L}^\infty x_j\to 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

See Nabakumar's comment.

Since $s_n:=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$ is convergent it is Cauchy.

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

There exists a $n_0$ s.t. for $m\ge n\ge n_0$

$|s_m-s_n| \lt \epsilon$.

$\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}|s_m-s_{n_0}| \le \epsilon$.

Can you finish?